# Model name is not defined on references column. I am trying to make a reference column for who created the bus_driver on sequelize js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Model name is not defined on references column. I am trying to make a reference column for who created the bus_driver on sequelize js.

I already created a User model and I'm trying to create a reference column, a column to determine who created the bus_driver. It says User is not defined. But if I try to remove the columns, it says cannot find module 'node: os'

```
"use strict";
const { Model } = require("sequelize");

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

// class Guide. Guide should be name of the file name.
  class Bus_driver extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The models/index file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
        // Default in every static associate
        this.belongsTo(models.User, {
            foreignKey: "created_by",
            type: DataTypes.UUID
        });

        // Default in every static associate
        this.belongsTo(models.User, {
            foreignKey: "updated_by",
            type: DataTypes.UUID
        });

        // Add your additional association here
        this.belongsTo(models.Bus_information , {
            foreignKey: "informationId",
            type: DataTypes.UUID
        });

        this.belongsTo(models.User , {
            foreignKey: "driverUserId",
            type: DataTypes.UUID
        });
        // End of your additional association 
    }
  }
  
  // Change Guide.init to {{Filename}}.init 
  Bus_driver.init(
    {
        // Default column this is a primary key
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            primaryKey: true,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        },

        // Default column this is the status of the row if it is deleted or active
        status: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
            defaultValue: "Active",
        },

        // Default column this is associate to user model who create the data
        created_by: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            references: {
                model: User,
                key: "id"
            }
        },

        // Default column this is associate to user model who update the data

        updated_by: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            references: {
                model: User,
                key: "id"
            }
        },
    
        // Add your additional columns here 
  
        // Could be driver or conductor
        type: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
            allowNull: true, 
        },



        // End of additional columns 
    },
    {
        sequelize,
        timestamps: true,
        createdAt: "created_at",
        updatedAt: "updated_at",
        modelName: "bus_driver", // Change model name base on file name
    }
  );

  // Change Guide to file name first letter should be in upper case
  return Bus_driver;
};
```

Comment: Based on _i just need to add `sequelize.modelName`_, the question should be closed as `not reproducible or caused by a typo`.

Answer (score 0):

i just need to add sequelize.modelName

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28933965)

Comment: @tomerpacific: It appears that they're answering their own question.

Comment: Where did you add `sequelize.modelName`?